# node-debug: why can't I set a breakpoint?

Tags: node.js, debugging, remote-debugging, node-debugger

I'm using node-debug and know which file and line for which I want to set a breakpoint.

Here's what happens:

`debug> setBreakpoint('./services/search.js', 359)
Warning: script './services/search.js' was not loaded yet.
You can't list source code right now`

Why can't I "list source code"? How can I add a breakpoint dynamically (without editing the source code to add `debugger`)?

I tried other tools for debugging, and would love to use Chrome Dev Tools, but don't think it's possible since our project is stuck on **v0.12.3**.

Also, some options are limited/tricky because I'm using Vagrant with a headless VM.

Comment: [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector) should work with 0.12.  (in node >= 6, use the built in `node --inspect` instead.)

Comment: @josh3736 I tried node-inspector and it doesn't seem to be working correctly. If I make a simple program with a console.log on the first line, nothing is logged. And, in the VM, if I curl localhost:8080, there's no response

Comment: With node-inspector, I'm pretty sure `console.log`ed things show up in stdout (like usual), not in the inspector console.  Additionally, your test script would likely complete before you have a chance to connect the debugger.  I'd run `node-inspector` in one window, then `node --debug-brk myscript.js` in another.  Then you can open the inspector in a web browser and begin execution.

Comment: @josh3736 with node-inspector, nothing shows up in stdout. And my small test script has `debug` lines, so no need for --debug-brk . I'm trying this with a tiny script: `var x = 2; console.log(x); debugger; x = 3; console.log(x);console.log('done');` Also trying this with a large Express application.

Comment: `debugger` statements have no effect if there's no debugger **attached** at the moment the line is executed -- so yes, `--debug-brk` is necessary with your test script.  (Although it is strange that your logs aren't showing up on stdout... `process.stdout.write`?)

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem in node 6.

There is precious little information about it on the net, which is a shame.

However, `node --inspect` and then using Chrome *does* work.